# Why is Jacoco Coverage Report for Branches saying if (a && b && c) is actually 6 branches?

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

My company has a requirement that we reach 90% test coverage for new code, and for Java code I am using gradle jacoco plugin which is nice; however, the branch coverage percentage is very difficult to improve to 90% when the number of branches starts increasing exponentially (exaggerating, it's probably geometric growth).

Here is a very contrived example:

```
public class Application {
    public static void test(boolean a, boolean b) {
        if (a && b) {
            System.out.println("true!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false!");
        }
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Application.test(true, true);
        Application.test(false, false);
    }
}
```

Here is what the coverage report looks like:

[image: Test Report Screenshot]

It also says that I have missed 1 of 4 branches, or in other words I have covered 3 of the 4 branches (75% branch coverage).

If I increase the number of booleans here, it seems the number of branches are n*2 where n is the number of booleans. So 3 (a,b,c) becomes 6 branches, and 10 becomes 20 branches. So I guess I don't understand what it means for there to be 6 or 20 branches in this case.

To satisfy this question - I could either

A) Configure jacoco to be more intuitive and treat if/else conditions as always having 2 branches (branch 1 is when the if executes, and branch 2 is when the else executes) -- lazy execution of sub-expressions could be tracked as line coverage or something else.

B) To explain more completely why it says there are 4, 6, 20 branches for these if/else with 2, 3, 10 booleans combined into 1 expression.

Edit -- to clarify where the confusion comes from:

1. How did I cover 3 branches in this example when there was only 2 calls?
2. Why does the number of branches for 3 booleans `(a && b && c)` in the example go to 6 branches, and 10 booleans `(a && b && c && .. && j)` go to 20 branches?

If each boolean is either true or false, and then I call the function with both states, how did I not get 100% branch coverage here? I am missing something.

Comment: The analysis is correct, that function implements behaviour for four different cases. The fact that the behaviour for three of them is (or at least, *is currently!*) the same doesn't matter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, but I still don't understand -- for 2 booleans the branch count is 4 which makes perfect sense. But why is 3 booleans then considered 6 branches, and 10 booleans considered 20? Also, how did I cover 3 cases when I only called the function 2 times?

Answer (score 5):

So I think I've figured out now why the reason the number of branches is equal to n*2 where n is the number of boolean expressions inside the if() condition.

Each boolean expression is its own branch, so in this example if we have `a && b && c` there are 3 different expressions each with 2 states so 6 branches. To cover all 6 branches, the test must ensure each variable is evaluated in both true and false states. The key part is that each expression must be evaluated, and in some cases they won't be because of lazy evaluation in Java.

```
public class Application {
    public static void test(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
        if (a && b && c) {
            System.out.println("true!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false!");
        }
    }
}
```

For the example `if (a && b && c)` when passing `a`, `b`, and `c` values all `true`, this actually covers 3 branches in a single execution. But if you pass all as `false`, it only covers one branch because `b` and `c` are never checked due to `a` being false and lazy evaluation.

To efficiently cover all 6 branches in this case, the test function must be called no less than 4 times to achieve 100% branch coverage.

```
/*
 * Using ? to indicate it can be true or false,
 * it won't matter because the variable would never be read due to lazy evaluation.
 */
Application.test(true, true, true);  // +3 branches covered
Application.test(true, true, false); // +1 branch covered
Application.test(true, false, ?);    // +1 branch covered
Application.test(false, ?, ?);       // +1 branch covered
                                     // total: 6 branches
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation, I ran into same issue and was able to fix the issue once I understood why it was failing coverage in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers partly explain the given example, but I would like to add a more general view here: Jacoco analyzes bytecode, and the branch coverage merely counts the targets of the binary conditional statements (branches) within.

Given the example above, but with three variables, we get 6 branches.

[image: snippet]

Looking at the bytecode we see that the short circuit operators are translated to three `ifeq`, which represent branch statements. Each of them has two possible targets, makes six altogether.

```
  public static void test(boolean, boolean, boolean);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: ifeq          23
       4: iload_1
       5: ifeq          23
       8: iload_2
       9: ifeq          23
      12: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      15: ldc           #22                 // String true!
      17: invokevirtual #24                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      20: goto          31
      23: getstatic     #16                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      26: ldc           #30                 // String false!
      28: invokevirtual #24                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      31: return
```

How to obtain full coverage can be seen in the corresponding control flow graph: The first test case `test(true,true,true)` takes the path along the top, covering three of the branches. For the remaining branches we need three more test cases, each taking another "exit" at the short circuit operators.

[image: cfg]

The required test cases for 100% branch coverage do not grow exponentially with the number of sub-expressions in the condition - in fact it's linear. Requiring to cover all possible combinations of sub-conditions (here: the values of a, b and c), however, is called multiple condition coverage ([wikipedia:coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)). Jacoco can not check that as the bytecode only knows binary conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you actually only need 3 tests to get 100% coverage. Testing the case when both are false doesn't provide any additional coverage. Intuitively, this should make some sense. You want it to print true unless at least one of its arguments is false.

The way you structure the code impacts the number of branches, too. If the requirement is to do one thing then when all of them are true and another when any one of them is false then you can do it with just two branches:

```
if (Stream.of(a,b).reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd).get(){
   System.out.println("true");
} else {
   System.out.println("false");
}
```

It looks kind of silly in a contrived example with just two inputs. With more than two inputs in an actual context, then it could make more sense. For example you could have something like a `List<ValidationRule>` and each element computes a boolean value. I won't say much more because it's beyond the scope of your original question, but it could be something worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing condition like if(a && b) so while running test case it will goes with all four scenarios as mentioned below.

```
result a     b
true   true  true
false  false true
false  true  false
false  false false
```

So you need to call this method four times to cover **`100% coverage`**.

You can also create some utility class which will generate these scenario according to number of arguments.

Comment: If that were true, then why does the number of branches increase to only 20 when I have 10 variables in the condition, e.g. `a && b && c ... & j` - I understand for 2 variables you need 2^2 test cases (4) but why for 10 variables do I not need 2^10 (1024) branches, and instead it says I need to do 20 branches?

Comment: Also - in my example, I have only 2 calls to the the test and yet somehow I have covered 3/4 cases, so I have 75% coverage already with only 2 calls, and you're saying I need to add 2 more executions to cover only one branch?

Comment: 75% is due to short circuit operator. As your first condition is false, it will not goes to check for second condition and that's why that scenario like `false,true` get cover. You are remaining with `true,false` scenario.

Comment: Why is it called 4 branches when it seems there are only 3 with the circuit breaker explanation 1= (false&&?) 2=(true&&false) 3=(true && true), where the ? doesn’t matter because it’s not evaluated due to lazy execution? Clearly I only need 3 (not 4 as you said) calls to the function to get 100% branch coverage.

Comment: As total condition are checked here are 4, but due to short circuit that `false,true` get cover and you need to write only 1 extra condition.